# Postgresql: issue with connecting to primery database after changing the archive directory address

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql cluster with one primary and one slave node.
The wal files were storing in primary database server and we decided to change its location to another directory which is mapped to a shared storage.
to make the address change, first I took down postgresql service on oth servers and then I have edited the postgresql.conf file in primary server to store wals in the new directory and also I changed the restore command in slave server to read wals from the new address.

after restarting the postgresql I'm getting this error:

Slave node:

```
CEST FATAL:  could not connect to the primary server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "replicationuser"
```

Primary node:

```
CEST FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "replicationuser"
CEST DETAIL:  Password does not match for user "replicationuser".
```

My question is, I have not made any changes in replication user password, I just changed the wal directory address. why should I get this error message?

Comment: Maybe you (or someone) had made *other* changes to config files which had never taken effect, then when you restarted the server they suddenly took effect and caused this problem.  For example, if replicationuser used to have a non-password based authentication method, then it wouldn't care that the password was wrong until suddenly a change in pg_hba to start using passwords became effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved by resetting the password for 'replicationuser' in primary node and restarting the slave node.

ALTER USER replicationuser PASSWORD '';